# duplicado consulta sql y cambio de datos

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Definicion del problema:

Estoy creando un sistema de cupones para una tienda en linea usando PHP(consultas PDO),Mysql.Pues bueno el sistema en 1 sola pagina muestra los cupones(tabla) y tambien los crea(formulario). en mi BD hay 2 tablas que juegan aqui en la implementacion del sistema de cupones. (1.Tabla Cupones - es nueva) y (2.Tabla productos - ya existente antes). entonces la tabla productos tiene un ultimo campo llamado id_coupon y cuando creo un cupon seleciono un producto de los que ya existen en la tienda y en la tabla productos inserto el id_coupon del cupon en el campo id_coupon de la tabla productos ubicado como ultima columna de la tabla y asi corresponden el cupon y producto correspondientes,asi mismo solo si corresponden la tabla lo muestra,el problema radica en que inserta cupon y lo enlaza en tabla productos de forma perfecta (solo la 1era vez).

Problema: solo funciona en la creacion del primer cupon todo enlazado (cupon-producto con id_coupon en las 2 tablas todo perfecto), pero! a la segunda cupon creado esta la falla (a veces me crea 2 cupones) y otras veces mas que todo me cambia el id_coupon del primer cupon por el segundo cupon que cree en un producto que no corresponde y me cambia el id_coupon correspondiente del cupon que se creo para el producto anterior.

Suena un poco confuso pero ese es mi problema y pues se me hace muy raro,porfavor espero su colaboracion y ya les comparto codigo (NO es laravel ni codeigniter ni prog orientada a objetos)

```
<?php require_once('header.php'); ?>

<?php
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_settings");
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($result as $row){
    $row['ValorDolarUS'];
}

?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['form1'])) {
    $valid = 1;
    
    if(empty($_POST['coupon_name'])) {
        $valid = 0;
        $error_message .= 'Coupon Name can not be empty<br>';
    }
    
    if(empty($_POST['coupon_start_date'])) {
        $valid = 0;
        $error_message .= 'Coupon Start Date can not be empty<br>';
    }
    
    if(empty($_POST['coupon_expire_date'])) {
        $valid = 0;
        $error_message .= 'Coupon Expire Date can not be empty<br>';
    }
    
    if(empty($_POST['coupon_code'])) {
        $valid = 0;
        $error_message .= 'Coupon Code can not be empty<br>';
    }
    
    if(empty($_POST['coupon_type'])) {
        $valid = 0;
        $error_message .= 'Coupon Type can not be empty<br>';
    }
    
    if(empty($_POST['coupon_discount'])) {
        $valid = 0;
        $error_message .= 'Coupon Discount can not be empty<br>';
    }
    
    if($valid == 1) {
        
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_settings");
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($result as $row){
            $row['ValorDolarUS'];
        }
        
        $ValorDolarUS = $row['ValorDolarUS'];
        
        $CurrentPriceConvertToDolar = ($_POST['coupon_discount'] / $ValorDolarUS);
        
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_coupons(
                                        coupon_name,
                                        coupon_start_date,
                                        coupon_expire_date,
                                        coupon_code,
                                        coupon_type,
                                        coupon_discount,
                                        ValorDolarUS
                                    ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $statement->execute(array(
                                        $_POST['coupon_name'],
                                        $_POST['coupon_start_date'],
                                        $_POST['coupon_expire_date'],
                                        $_POST['coupon_code'],
                                        $_POST['coupon_type'],
                                        $CurrentPriceConvertToDolar,
                                        $ValorDolarUS
                                    ));
    
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_coupons");
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach($result as $row) {
            $selected_product_id_coupon = $row['id_coupon'];
        }

        $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_product");
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach($result as $row) {
            $selected_product_id = $row['p_id'];
        }

        $statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE tbl_product SET id_coupon=? WHERE p_id=?");
        $statement->execute(array($selected_product_id_coupon,$selected_product_id));
        
        $success_message = 'Coupon is created successfully and its aplied for selected product.';
        
        $reloadpage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."#CouponsForm";
        header("Location:$reloadpage");
        exit();
        
    }

}
?>
```

[image: TABLA CUPONES]

[image: TABLA PRODUCTO]

Comment: en esta parte específica de este código aquí el problema: (EN LA CONSULTA SELECCIONADA AGREGO DONDE P_ID IGUAL AL PRODUCTO SELECCIONADO PARA DESCUENTO EN FORMULARIO)...........$statement = $pdo->prepare(" SELECCIONE * DESDE tbl_product DONDE p_id=?");
$estado de cuenta->ejecutar(array($_POST['producto_seleccionado_para_descuento']));
$resultado = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($resultado como $fila) {
$selected_product_id = $fila['p_id'];
}

Comment: ese comentario ponelo en la pregunta.. no?